# If I leave a comment, then delete it, does a person still get notified?

Tags: support, comments, notifications

Sometimes I leave a comment, then think better of it -- perhaps I decide to answer instead.  If I delete the comment, does the user still get notified that new comments are available or does the notification take this into account?  Are the comments hard-deleted or soft-deleted?

Answer (score 10):

The answer is yes.  From my experience you will always get a notification.

The same also goes for answers to your questions.

Comment: So this might explain the phantom notifications that I sometimes seem to get, where there are no new answers or comments?

Comment: Yup.  You can see the comments or answers in the users profile too.  So, if you can figure out who may have deleted the post, you can even see what it was.

Comment: This is a great _feature_ in my opinion. You can make comments like _Shall we clear up this comment stream?_ and delete it right after without the need to track if it got attention. Super!

Answer (score 5):

I have noticed this usually has a latency probably due to caching.

If you don't delete it immediately though, the person should get a notification.

Comment: So if I do delete it immediately, does that mean there shouldn't be a problem?

Comment: @tv: **Should** but I wouldn't count on it. Better advice would be to think through your comments before posting them.

Comment: I have posted a couple comments and deleted them on your question.

Comment: So. When I checked the last notification was for jingguy's answer -- which should have been too old to trigger the notification.  Your comments did not show up there.

Comment: Righto. I deleted them within 15 or 20 seconds of posting them.