# Pinged Person in a Comment Deleted within Seconds: How does notification work?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications, comment-replies, deleted-comments

I recently deleted a comment within seconds of posting it. I had pinged a user in that comment.

Will the user get notified? Will the notification be automatically removed, as it is obsolete? Will the user be able to see my deleted comment?

This question is related to [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19092/if-i-leave-a-comment-then-delete-it-does-a-person-still-get-notified) pointed out but not the same.

1. I am not asking about notification to owner of the question or notification to the user who posted an answer. I am asking about notification to a commenter who was pinged using `@`.
2. My question is a special case for which the given answers contradict each other. (check the comments in the second answer)
3. I am specifically asking about deletion within seconds. This was the case even before the question was edited. You will notice I only edited the title too reflect that now.

Comment: I agree they are related. Though I am not asking about the the person who answered the question or the person who posted the question. My question is very specific about a user pinged using `@` in a deleted comment who may not own the question or have posted an answer

Comment: Still duplicate, it doesn't matter if you delete the comment seconds or years after posting, the question is whether the notification gets deleted or not.

Comment: @ShadowWizard, did you read the comments below the second answer in the question linked as I pointed out. If the comment is deleted within seconds, it seems that the notification do not appear. However that is mentioned nowhere in the answer. And the answer is a stark contradiction of what is said in the comment. So I think it is a valid question. Either way I would like an answer. Will the notification appear or no?

Comment: I am not asking if the notification will get deleted either. I am asking will the notification *appear*?

Comment: Comments are irrelevant. All that matters is the question, sometimes the answers. I agree the matter is still open and not officially answered, but that's what we have bounties for, and someone already started a bounty there trying to draw official response once and for all.

Comment: you seem to misunderstand. That question was decided on what happens when a comment is deleted. The answer was unambigously this: The notification will be delivered. I am asking about a special case, which the question pointed out was not about. Or will asking a question about a general case where the answer won't apply to a special case make the question about special case invalid? May be the answer was not accepted but the question was NOT about what I am asking here

Comment: The notification is created in the code in the same time the comment is stored to database so the answer is obviously "yes, the notification is created and delivered". However, if it's being deleted when the comment is deleted, the target user has very little chance of actually seeing it. So bottom line, still can't see the point of having separate question here. (not saying you should delete it, just saying I don't think it should be reopened)

Comment: That's ok, all i wanted was to know the answer. Thanks. That comment seemed to tell that there was some latency in the notification delivery due to caching and if the comment is deleted within seconds, due to the latency the notification is not delivered. That's why I wanted to know if it will be delivered.

Comment: Maybe once you confirm it you can answer at the linked post for people to know the correct answer to this question?