# Edit question when offering bounty to someone else's question

Tags: discussion, edits, bounties

Suppose, there is already a question by another user that is very similar to the one I want to ask and that has answers (maybe including an accepted one).
I want to offer a bounty for that question, but at the same time there is a little more that I want to ask. What is the right way to do this:

- Open another question (what if it is marked as duplicate?), adding that part that I want to ask and start bounty, if I do not get an answer.
- Edit the question, just adding that little part (also maybe mentioning that it was added by another user) and then start a bounty?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are interested in an answer to a specific aspect of a question that wasn’t addressed in the existing answers or only addressed insufficiently, the default way to do so would be the individual text you can add to your bounty, e.g., like [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19092/255554) (the linked example will self-destruct in a week, the screenshot won’t):

> [image]

If that specific aspect was not explicitly or implicitly asked for in the original question and not addressed in the answers, it’s probably better to ask a separate question. However, this is only a guideline and really depends on the actual question in question and also on the individual Stack Exchange.

In no case, it is a good idea to repeat the existing question and add the specific aspect, you are interested in. Rather only ask a question about that aspect only and refer to the other question.

Editing-in an additional question into an existing question will likely be a too radical edit in most cases, so you should refrain from it. (Again this is only a guideline. E.g., if the original author of the question added some clarifications in a comment, you can edit this into the question.)